# How do I organize the .NET 6 Minimal Web Api routes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

How do I move my "/api/employees" route out of program.cs?

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

I have seen the microsoft guys do something like this:

```
public class EmployeeApi
{
    public static void MapRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder routes)
    {
        routes.MapGet("/api/employees", async  ([FromServices] AppDbContext db) =>
        {
            return await db.Employees.ToListAsync();
        });

        routes.MapGet("api/employees/{id}", async (int id, [FromServices] AppDbContext db) =>
        {
            return await db.Employees.FindAsync(id);
        });
    }
}
```

They created a new class. But I do not know how to implement this so that the program knows these routes exist.

Answer (score 6):

You can create an extension method and call it in your `program.cs` file:

```cs
public static class EmployeeApi
{
    public static void MapEmployeesRoutes(this IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapGet("/api/employees", async  ([FromServices] AppDbContext db) =>
        {
            return await db.Employees.ToListAsync();
        });

        app.MapGet("api/employees/{id}", async (int id, [FromServices] AppDbContext db) =>
        {
            return await db.Employees.FindAsync(id);
        });
    }
}
```

and in your `program.cs` file call your method:

```
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.MapEmployeesRoutes();
```

Your `program.cs` file should be like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers(); 

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.MapControllers(); 
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!"); 
app.MapEmployeesRoutes();

app.Run();
public static class EmployeeApi
{
    public static void MapEmployeesRoutes(this IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapGet("/api/employees", async  ([FromServices] AppDbContext db) =>
        {
            return await db.Employees.ToListAsync();
        });

        app.MapGet("api/employees/{id}", async (int id, [FromServices] AppDbContext db) =>
        {
            return await db.Employees.FindAsync(id);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error on app.MapEmployeesRoutes(); Visual Studio does not recognize. I have imported all usings.

Comment: C:\Users\chad\source\repos\MainSolution\FromScratchApi\Program.cs(50,5): error CS1061: 'WebApplication' does not contain a definition for 'MapEmployeeApi' and no accessible extension method 'MapEmployeeApi' accepting a first argument of type 'WebApplication' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\chad\source\repos\MainSolution\FromScratchApi\FromScratchApi.csproj]

Comment: @ChadLomax Show all of your program file in your question

Comment: The point was to take it out of the Program.cs file

Comment: MapEmployeeApi   isn't that supposed to be MapEmployeeRoutes

Comment: I named my method MapEmployeeApi. its the same thing.

Comment: ah, bad name, there's likely something you've done to the extension method class, maybe not public, maybe not static

Comment: This issue was I was missing the "this" in the MapEmployeeApi extension method. As soon as I added "this" to: "public static void MapEmployeeApi(this IEndpointRouteBuilder routes)" VS picked it up in Program.cs. I don't know why but I will look into Thank you.

Comment: the this is the key magic needed for an extension method

Comment: I think I see. In this case it extends IEndpointRouteBuilder.

Comment: An example of the described approach – https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult/tree/master/samples/WebApiMinimal